# Trouble adding div with 100% height, and keeping existing content vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

The below code works as intended (full width background image, with horizontally and vertically aligned text overlapping it), but I want to make a couple of changes. Instead of having a background image for `#banner`, I want to switch it to a color, and add a `div` before `.teaser` that is `width: 1366px`, `height: 100%` of parent, and includes a background image set to `cover`. I still need `.teaser` vertically aligned though. I've been struggling with this for awhile, so any help would be very much appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/exczzyje/

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="valign">
        <div class="teaser">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Tagline</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67%;
    height: calc(67% - 123px);
    background: #000 url('images/banner.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#banner[id] {
    display: table;
    position: static;
}

#banner #valign {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
}

#banner #valign[id] {
    display: table-cell;
    position: static;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#banner .teaser {
    width: 960px;
    margin: -12px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 21px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}

#banner .teaser h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 45px;
}

#banner .teaser h1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    margin: 18px auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bfbfbf;
}

#banner .teaser p {
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exczzyje/

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want #banner to have a background-color, and for another div centered inside with 1366px width, 100% height of #banner, with the background image instead (without messing up my vertical alignment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a container around the outside instead.

Updated HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="valign">
            <div class="teaser">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>Tagline</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67%;
    height: calc(67% - 123px);
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#banner {
    width: 1366px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000 url('images/banner.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exczzyje/12/)**

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
}

#banner #valign {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#newDiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1366px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000 url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#banner .teaser {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 21px 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#banner .teaser h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 45px;
}

#banner .teaser h1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    margin: 18px auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #bfbfbf;
}

#banner .teaser p {
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}
```